# Problems with Ajax calls and serialization macOS Chrome

Tags: ajax, macos, google-chrome, serialization

I have been testing a piece of code that I use for the purpose of auto saving the stuff from the site. It was achieved with ajax calls and serializing all the fields that are being displayed. It does work perfectly on all the major browsers on Windows e.g. Firefox, Chrome, IE, Edge etc. However, when it comes to mac there seems to be an issue with Chrome. Does anyone know something about the bug with macOS, Chrome and ajax/ data serialization that has been reported?

Comment: what have you done, can you add your code?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot really do it. However, the thing I do is serializing all the elements displayed on a page, and then send them to MVC controller with the use of an ajax call. The problem is, I cannot reproduce the error - I was trying to do it on mac on chrome as well and there was nothing wrong with it.I have been said that it did not work as expected. From my own testing it seems to be absolutely fine on both windows and mac. I did a lot of reading on it and it might have been caused by an issue with JavaScript on client side or maybe some kind of plugin that stops it from working.